# how did an empty useState array match with the data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

everyone.
The initial value of `cartItems` is an empty array `[]`. When we add `product`  on `onAdd` how can it match with `cartItems` when it's empty.

```
  import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Header from "./components/Header"
import Main from "./components/Main"
import Basket from "./components/Basket"
import data from "./data"
import styles from "./index.css"

function App() {
  const {products} =data
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
  const onAdd = (product) => {
    const exist = cartItems.find((x) => x.id === product.id);
    if (exist) {
      setCartItems(
        cartItems.map((x) =>
          x.id === product.id ? { ...exist, qty: exist.qty + 1 } : x
        )
      );
    } else {
      setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...product, qty: 1 }]);
    }
  };
  return (<div>
    <div>
        <Header/>
         <div className="header2" >
         <Main ff={products} onAdd={onAdd} />
         <Basket onAdd={onAdd}  cartItems={cartItems}/>
         </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: what's the problem here? when you do map or find it will loop only if there is some data in array. I think your code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In **ADD** function, first you're checking if the item exists or not. If the item exists, then you're increasing the quantity value by one. 
The Expression

```
setCartItems(
        cartItems.map((x) =>
          x.id === product.id ? { ...exist, qty: exist.qty + 1 } : x
        )
      );
```

IS equivalent to

```
const addingExsitingValue = (value,index,cartArray) => {
  if(value.id===product.id){
    cartArray[index] = {...product, qty: product.qty + 1 } // here's a mistake you made, the exist is simple true or false, it should be product
  }
}
cartItems.forEach(addingExisitingValue);
```

AND
`setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...product, qty: 1 }]);`
is just adding the newly product to the cartItems, which is equivalent to

```
cartItem.push({...product,qty:1})
```

I hope now i makes sense to you